# Ceiling fixture wiring

Tags: electrical, wiring

I’m changing the ceiling fan in my kitchen. After taking it down and disconnecting I can’t remember how they had it wired up. I’m used to a ground, neutral white, and black hot. This one seems to have 2 black in a loop, 1 single black, and three “brown” connected.

[image]

Comment: Location in the world will be helpful.  Brown and black might be old UK/Europe colours.   The single black looks to be damaged, part of the copper is showing, needs to replaced or fixed.

Comment: Cut that broken wire back behind the break if you have enough length, or at least wrap it with vinyl tape.

Comment: The browns are just discolored whites. You probably have a switch loop and a passthrough cable. Connect to the single black and the white bundle.

Comment: @isherwood I started writing up an answer that is essentially a wordy version of your first 2 comments, which came in as I was staring at the picture trying to figure it out. So go ahead and answer.

Comment: Or this? [Why are there three cables coming into my ceiling fan box?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/195872/why-are-there-three-cables-coming-into-my-ceiling-fan-box)

Comment: Or this? [How should connect my light to the wires in these three cables?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/208112/how-should-connect-my-light-to-the-wires-in-these-three-cables)

Comment: Crime scene forensic investigation shows, you removed the fan wires, then screw back the wire nuts, too cover up. Now nobody knows what it was. Lesson learned, in this day and age with cell phone taking as many picture as you want shall be used.

Comment: The box probably isn't rated for a ceiling fan either.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact thank you

Comment: If those brown wires are actually just discolored white wires, that is some _incredibly_ even discoloration. It's also rather disconcerting that it got hot enough in there to discolor all that insulation, and I'd be concerned about the quality of the insulation now. (Especially given the obvious age of this wiring with the woven cloth outer layer.) It may well be time to consider a rewire, at least of this particular light.